# long list selector not scrolling properly

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, longlistselector

My LongListSelector is not scrolling properly. When I scroll the list, it automatically reaching back to the top with its rubber band effect.

**xaml** is

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Height="2000">
    <toolkit:LongListSelector x:Name="ItemList" DataContext="Item" IsFlatList="True" StretchingBottom="LoadMoreData">
        <toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Tag="{Binding ItemID}" Loaded="Grid_Loaded" MaxWidth="361" MaxHeight="100">
                        // some xaml code
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </toolkit:LongListSelector>
</Grid>
```

can anyone help me ?
thanku

Answer (score 1):

It's not scrolling correctly because you set the Height of the parent Grid to 2000. This causes the LongListSelector to take as much space as it may need as long as it's less than 2000 and only then starts scrolling. Considering you only have 800 (or a bit more) of height, you don't see the scrolling properly.

Comment: hey @igrali thanks for ur answer. above problem is solved but when i scroll the longListSelector, sometimes it becomes unresponsive can u tell me why ?

Comment: How many items are inside? It shouldn't really be happening. What do you mean by unresponsive? Sometimes it may seem like it's unresponsive, but that's because the items are continuously being loaded as you scroll the list.

Comment: +1. same prob here. Yes its the reason that Longlistselector height has been increased, so the scroller doesn't work. But now I decrease the height to the phone height, now it worked... thanks.